# Generating conditional Unique Identifiers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint

I've an application where I read all the sub-folders inside a folder. I want to read only the folders created by my application. So I want to generate unique identifiers as folder names which should be recognizable as the ones created by my applications. If any other folders are copied in the same location I want to ignore those folders by checking their names.

Comment: Why not just store the current names of the folders?

Comment: You must have already thought about having prefixes or suffixes to your application created folders. Are there any issues with it? Other approach could be to create a unique file (some kind of encryption) inside your app created folder to separate it from other folders. Hope it helps.

Comment: Anyone can create folders with those prefixes/suffixes.

Comment: @Lasse - I need to load the folders dynamically. It is just like an add-on framework where if an add-on is installed I just get a folder created here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can rely on the file system being NTFS you could tag all your folders with an alternate datastream check if such a stream is present while reading the list ... just an idea

//edit

if you want some tag that only your app can create .... place a file/alternate datastream in the folder containing its path, and a message authentication code (like hmacMD5 or something like that)